# Api blockchain.com registration returns 500 error

Tags: rest, api

Need get API KEY in blockchain.com
But api registration return 500!

https://api.blockchain.info/customer/signup

500: Could not get a resource from the pool

Can anybody suggest any BTC WALLET GENERATOR API?

Comment: I am getting the same, probably it's an error within their backend.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Coinbase Commerce.** They support many cryptocurrencies. They don't generate a wallet but they have a checkout page which is awesome.

They have their own API. Sign up at [this link](http://commerce.coinbase.com)
Hope this helps you out.